# Is it possible to set a elements Max length with a complex type/any inside of it?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Is something like this possible? I am trying to see if it’s possible to actually set a max length constraint to an element that contains an  in xsd.

```
    <xs:element name="example">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="50" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Is *maxLength*  facet not enough?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a mixed type. And it is not possible to restrict the text content of a mixed type.

Instead you could insert another tag with a simple type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you like with XSD 1.1 assertions. But there's no way of doing it in XSD 1.0.